# navbar-fixed-top background color

Tags: navbar

I want to change background color of nav menu. When I put styling code in html page then the color of the nav successfully changes such below:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:red;">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
    </nav>
```

But when I try to apply this via a CSS file then nothing happens.

```
.navbar-default{
height:100px;
background-color: red;
border-color: #E7E7E7;
 }
```

Please help

Comment: you are using three different classes, navbar, navbar-default, and navbar-fixed-top. what about colour definitions there? also, the nav element itself may have a rule of its own. please show the full css of the nav element and all three classes.

Comment: I added the full CSS already. When I delete style="background-color:red;" snippet then nothing happens

Comment: you are only showing the rule for navbar-default. trying the below in a test file works fine on my end: <style type="text/css">
nav {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
</style>
<nav>blah</nav>

Comment: Dear PHClaus, I tried everything in CSS file. I applied same rule for .navbar-fixed-top ,navbar and navbar default. My only purpose is changing the backcolor. Is it really so difficult?

Comment: as mentioned above, it works here. are using a framework of sorts? if so, check the rules provided there. else, good luck.